# Simple XNA 2d physics library

Tags: c#, xna

Working on a 2D project and wanted some recommendations on a simple 2d physics library for use in C# with the XNA framework. I was looking at Farseer or physics2d. Anyone have any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using Farseer for 2D. It comes with good demos and does what it needs to well enough. It is extensible easily enough thanks to the source being both provided and clearly written.

If you outgrow it you will at least know far better what your requirements are. It only took me an afternoon to learn it and start extending it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I agree, better to start with something that may be too simple before going with something that may be overkill or overly complex.

Answer (score 6):

There's a good list posted on the [XNA Forums](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/7574.aspx).

If you're only dealing with 2D, Farseer is very nice to work with, and would probably be my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some work on a new physics engine called Jitter2D.

[Jitter2D Source](http://code.google.com/p/jitterphysics/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Other/Jitter2D)